# Does the Geocode support any way to get cardinal points and route type specifically called out?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

So for example the address "NE 15th Ave, Minneapolis, MN 55413" has cardinal points NE and route type Ave.  We can put the full list of route types into properties or data somewhere and parse them fairly easily but that still isn't ideal.  Some addresses also have these cardinal points after the address number to add to the confusion: "1231 Bankhead Hwy SW, Graysville, Alabama" as an example.  I haven't seen any cases where there is a pre and post direction/cardinal point, but the automatic parsing of these could become a real issue if it does occur (and I'm sure it does).  We interface into ISO Databases and that is sadly how they have their location information split out and while there is other magic we could perform it is not close to ideal.  Does anyone know of any silver bullets or pieces to this I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

An address is a very complicated thing when comes to automate it. There are several reasons:

- historically address was never invented to be processed into latitude/longitude.
- address consist sometimes of more than 10 parts
- address is not geolocation

Read this article at [The Complexity of Mapping Physical to Geolocation Address](https://csv2geo.com/blog/post/the-complexity-of-mapping-physical-to-geolocation-address)
It will give you an idea how address tokens are constructed.
Usually an address has less tokens and that is what most people are used to work with.
You would have to do mapping to each address token from the database, aggregate each part, and finally build the whole address. Also keep in mind there is a secondary unit address part that brings another level of complexity.
After the mapping is done, the rest is simply to find a proper geocoder (like google ) to process the data.
You can also play with this batch geocoder tool [CSV2GeoData](https://csv2geo.com) to feel how the address tokens are grouped together.